# Is there a way to import a script from Celtx into Final Draft?

Tags: software, screenwriting

Is there a way to import a script from Celtx into Final Draft? Going to switch and it seems as though my script is "locked" into Celtx's format. I'm hoping this is possible and that there isn't a huge typing project in my future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Final Draft* will open a **text file exported** from *Celtx* and give you the option of converting it to standard formatting for a screenplay.

Quite detailed instructions are given in the [Final Draft support forum](http://support.finaldraft.com/article.aspx?cid=1001&aid=546)

Comment: Thanks so much! This will make my transition to Final Draft easier. Appreciate it.